# Какой самый оптимальный способ, чтобы получить элемент множества?

Tags: python

```
some_set = {1, 6, 12}

for element in some_set:
    break
```

Какие еще способы можно использовать? Кроме `element = list(some_set)[0]`.

Comment: some_set.pop() - возвратит первый хранимый элемент. some_set.remove(x) - удалит элемент со значением x.

Comment: Да, но тогда, чтобы сохранить изначальное множество придется добавить удаленный элемент обратно. В итоге получится также не красиво, как и цикл с break.

Comment: Вы понимаете, что множество это неупорядоченная структура? В нём нет понятия первого, второго, третьего и т.д. элемента.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Конечно понимаю, поэтому я не спрашиваю,  как получить элемент по индексу из множества. Просто бывают ситуации, когда нет возможности конвертировать set  в list, я обычно использую цикл с break, но как по мне выглядит это коряво, вот и решил узнать какие еще бывают способы.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825/how-to-retrieve-an-element-from-a-set-without-removing-it

Comment: @0andriy Спасибо! Значит цикл с break самый лучший вариант.

Answer (score 0):

К элементам множества можно получить доступ только с помощью `in`

Comment: `in` проверяет наличие элемента слева в итер. множестве справа

Answer (score 0):

Для разнообразия (из приемлемого):

```
set2 = {1, 2, 3, 4}

for num, elem in enumerate(set2):
    if num == 3:
        print(elem)
#4
```